# Pacf lag axe , is not an integer

Tags: r, time-series, arima, arma

I'm trying to use ARIMA process to predict the behaviour of a time series, the probleme I face is that I can't get the order of each component of ARIMA, the lag is between 0 and 1, same goes for the acf.
The time series has no tendency, and I guess no seasonality. 
[image: this is the plot of the pacf I found] [image: How the TS looks like]

My question is : Does this mean that ARIMA orders are all 0s, and if so, is the HoltWinters a good (or the best) solution for modelling this kind of TS ?

Comment: Have you checked the stationarity of your time series before estimating pacf? If the second figure is the time plot of your series, it does not seem stationary to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Something* is driving those peaks in the second plot - it's pretty much impossible that all these peaks would have the same height just by chance. These are likely large orders from one particular customer. Find out how to forecast these, and don't worry about fitting any model until after you have accounted for the largest drivers.

Comment: Okey, thanks for your response, what about the acf and pacf lag axes ? are those peaks the reason I have lag between 0 and 1

Comment: The $x$ axis of your (P)ACF plots do not count in time buckets, but in full seasonal periods. Here, you have weekly data, so the axis counts in fractions of full years. "0.1" refers to a tenth of a year, or a little more than one month, or about 5.2 weeks. `acf()` and `pacf()` return the autocorrelation coefficients in a vector that is again named by fractions of the full seasonal cycle, so you can extract them using `pacf(...)[1]` and so on.